# How to auto redirect a webpage from ajax response if the session is expired?

Tags: javascript, ajax, session

This is my javascript..

```
function rDir() {
    window.location="./index.php?status=session";
}
```

my ajax response from php code is

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    rDir();
</script>
```

if I use `header('Location:index.php?status=session;);` in php it works.. but it loads the index.php content inside div...

How do I load redirect a main page through ajax if the session has expired?

Answer (score 0):

though im not very proficient in PHP 
but im assuming that if your session is expired then you will be getting a response code for redirection like 3xx. 
In which case browser automatically issues a new request and downloads the page to which the request redirects. This is done transparently to your ajax request so finally in the success handler you will get the HTML of the login page.

by the way you have written that you your self are setting `Location Header` im also assuming you are your self handling the requests even in the session is expired. in which case

1.either you can change the status code being returned.
2.use a ajax service inside a look checking session status at preodic intervals. if you find that session has expired redirect to the login page.

Comment: as i told u already, m getting the respone of redirect from php but it doesn't redirect my page, it just loads the content of login page in my DIV.

Comment: that is because the request is an ajax request. The Page that is open will not redirect but the specific request which is issued afer session expiration will be redirected.

Comment: if i refresh the page or click on some non-ajax link, it gets redirected. i want to redirect it also when anyone click on ajax link too.. ajax link just displays the message but doesn't redirect.

Comment: @user2788392 as Parv Sharma said you are redirecting the request that mean that the request will not load your script i will load index.php?session=awesome try one of my solution

Answer (score 0):

To achieve that their are a lot of ways:

1-The simplest:

```
Var MustBe = "script type="\text/javascript\">rDir();</script>";
if(Request.ResponseText == MustBe ){
rDir();
}
```

2-Professional:

```
$('body').append(request.responsetext);
```

3-A good way:

```
if(Request.responsetext.indexof("rDir();") !== -1){
rDir();
}
```

I have chosen those ways because it is simple to implement in your code.

Comment: `echo '{"msg": "Login Success!!! Redirecting...","rdir": "home.php"}';` is the JSON response for the ajax request that i m using for redirecting in my specific login ajax function. But in this question, i m using the other ajax function to retrieve data.. well, the data is more in this context, i m not using the JSON format or else redirecting it from ajax Function, i want to perform it out from the ajax function. and also i m not using JQuery.. anyway thank you for response.. :)